# Show that the Riemann sphere complement the unit disc is a hyperbolic Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

I am trying to understand what $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \backslash \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ in the area of Riemann surfaces.

$\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the Riemann sphere and $\bar {\mathbb{D}}$ is the closure of the unit disk.

1. Is $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \backslash \bar{\mathbb{D}} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| > 1 \} \cup \{\infty \}$?
2. I think this is a non-simply connected space because there is a hole in the middle of it and I am guessing that I will not be able to find a homotopy for this space. If so, how do I show that this is the case?
3. Is this a hyperbolic Riemann surface?

For 2, from what I have learnt one method to show that this is a hyperbolic Riemann surface is by looking at its universal covering, and another is by showing that it is biholomorphic to another hyperbolic surface, but I am not sure how to use either of these methods here.

P.S. This is my first time asking a question here. Thanks!

Comment: 1 yes 2 no (it's an open disk, you should think of it at $S^2$ minus a closed disk) 3 yes (since it's an open disk. Any simply connected Riemann surface is hyperbolic if not $\widehat{\Bbb C}$ or $\Bbb C$)

Comment: Thanks! With regards to 2, could you please elaborate as to how I can see this as an open disc more, as I am not familiar with $S^2$?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to 1 and 3 is yes. Furthermore the formula that lies behind this answer shows that there is no "hole in the middle of it" and that the answer to 2 is no. All these answers are obtained using  the inversion formula 
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{z} & \quad\text{if $z \not\in \{0,\infty\}$} \\ \infty & \quad\text{if $z=0$} \\
0 & \quad\text{if $z = \infty$}
\end{cases}
$$
which maps $\hat{\mathbb C} \setminus \bar{\mathbb D}$ to $\mathbb D$ biholomorphically.

Comment: Thanks! Is it true that I see each of this equation as an atlas of $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \backslash \overline{\mathbb{D}}$?

Comment: It would put it a little differently. This equation *is* a coordinate chart of $\hat{\mathbb C} - \bar{\mathbb D}$, or what's better it is a coordinate chart of $\hat{\mathbb C} - \{0\}$. Also, the identity map is a coordinate chart of $\hat{\mathbb C} - \{\infty\}=\mathbb C$. Together those two coordinate charts form an atlas of $\hat{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!